# Find min value for every 5 hour interval

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My df

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", 1),
  ("1", 1),
  ("1", 2),
  ("1", 4),
  ("1", 5),
  ("1", 6),
  ("1", 8),
  ("1", 12),
  ("1", 12),
  ("1", 13),
  ("1", 14),
  ("1", 15),
  ("1", 16)
).toDF("id", "time")
```

For this case the first interval starts from 1 hour. So every row up to 6 (1 + 5) is part of this interval.

But 8 - 1 > 5, so the second interval starts from 8 and goes up to 13.

Then I see that 14 - 8 > 5, so the third one starts and so on.

The desired result

```
+---+----+--------+
|id |time|min_time|
+---+----+--------+
|1  |1   |1       |
|1  |1   |1       |
|1  |2   |1       |
|1  |4   |1       |
|1  |5   |1       |
|1  |6   |1       |
|1  |8   |8       |
|1  |12  |8       |
|1  |12  |8       |
|1  |13  |8       |
|1  |14  |14      |
|1  |15  |14      |
|1  |16  |14      |
+---+----+--------+
```

I'm trying to do it using min function, but don't know how to account for this condition.

```
val window = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"time")
df
.select($"id", $"time")
.withColumn("min_time", when(($"time" - min($"time").over(window)) <= 5, min($"time").over(window)).otherwise($"time"))
.show(false)
```

what I get

```
+---+----+--------+
|id |time|min_time|
+---+----+--------+
|1  |1   |1       |
|1  |1   |1       |
|1  |2   |1       |
|1  |4   |1       |
|1  |5   |1       |
|1  |6   |1       |
|1  |8   |8       |
|1  |12  |12      |
|1  |12  |12      |
|1  |13  |13      |
|1  |14  |14      |
|1  |15  |15      |
|1  |16  |16      |
+---+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with your first idea of using aggregation function on a [window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html). But instead of using some combination of Spark's already defined functions, you can define your own [Spark's user-defined aggregate function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html) (UDAF).

### Analysis

As you correctly supposed, we should use a kind of min function on a window. On the rows of this window, we want to implement the following rule:

> Given rows sorted by `time`, if the difference between the `min_time` of the previous row and the `time` of the current row is greater than 5, then the current row's `min_time` should be current row's `time`, else the current row's `min_time` should be previous row's `min_time`.

However, with the aggregate functions provided by Spark, we can't access to the previous row's `min_time`. It exists a `lag` function, but with this function we can only access to the already present values of previous rows. As the previous row's `min_time` is not already present, we can't access it.

Thus we have to define our own aggregate function

### Solution

#### Defining a tailor-made aggregate function

To define our aggregate function, we need to create a class that extends the [Aggregator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html) abstract class. Below is the complete implementation:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

object MinByInterval extends Aggregator[Integer, Integer, Integer] {

  def zero: Integer = null

  def reduce(buffer: Integer, time: Integer): Integer = {
    if (buffer == null || time - buffer > 5) time else buffer
  }

  def merge(b1: Integer, b2: Integer): Integer = {
    throw new NotImplementedError("should not use as general aggregation")
  }

  def finish(reduction: Integer): Integer = reduction

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Integer] = Encoders.INT

  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Integer] = Encoders.INT

}
```

We use `Integer` for input, buffer and output types. We chose `Integer` as it is a nullable `Int`. We could have used `Option[Int]`, however the documentation of Spark advises to not recreate objects in aggregators methods for performance issues, what would happens if we use complex types like `Option`.

We implement the rule defined in Analysis section in `reduce` method:

```scala
def reduce(buffer: Integer, time: Integer): Integer = {
  if (buffer == null || time - buffer > 5) time else buffer
}
```

Here `time` is the value in the column time of the current row, and `buffer` the value previously computed, so corresponding to the column min_time of the previous row. As in our window we sort the rows by `time`, `time` is always greater than `buffer`. The null buffer case only happens when treating first row.

The method `merge` is not used when using aggregate function over a window, so we don't implement it.

`finish` method is identity method as we don't need to perform final calculation on our aggregated value and output and buffer encoders are `Encoders.INT`

#### Calling user defined aggregate function

Now we can call our user defined aggregate function with the following code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udaf}

val minTime = udaf(MinByInterval)
val window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("time")
df.withColumn("min_time", minTime(col("time")).over(window))
```

### Run

Given the input dataframe in the question, we get:

```
+---+----+--------+
|id |time|min_time|
+---+----+--------+
|1  |1   |1       |
|1  |1   |1       |
|1  |2   |1       |
|1  |4   |1       |
|1  |5   |1       |
|1  |6   |1       |
|1  |8   |8       |
|1  |12  |8       |
|1  |12  |8       |
|1  |13  |8       |
|1  |14  |14      |
|1  |15  |14      |
|1  |16  |14      |
+---+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Input data

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", 1),
  ("1", 1),
  ("1", 2),
  ("1", 4),
  ("1", 5),
  ("1", 6),
  ("1", 8),
  ("1", 12),
  ("1", 12),
  ("1", 13),
  ("1", 14),
  ("1", 15),
  ("1", 16),
  ("2", 4),
  ("2", 8),
  ("2", 10),
  ("2", 11),
  ("2", 11),
  ("2", 12),
  ("2", 13),
  ("2", 20)
).toDF("id", "time")
```

The data must be sorted, otherwise the result will be incorect.

```
val window = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"time")
df
  .withColumn("min", row_number().over(window))
  .as[Row]
  .map(_.getMin)
  .show(40)
```

After, I create a case class. `var min` is used to hold the minimum value and is only updated when the conditions are met.

```
case class Row(id:String, time:Int, min:Int){
  def getMin: Row = {
    if(time - Row.min > 5 || Row.min == -99 || min == 1){
      Row.min = time
    }
    Row(id, time, Row.min)
  }
}

object Row{
  var min: Int = -99
}
```

Result

```
+---+----+---+
| id|time|min|
+---+----+---+
|  1|   1|  1|
|  1|   1|  1|
|  1|   2|  1|
|  1|   4|  1|
|  1|   5|  1|
|  1|   6|  1|
|  1|   8|  8|
|  1|  12|  8|
|  1|  12|  8|
|  1|  13|  8|
|  1|  14| 14|
|  1|  15| 14|
|  1|  16| 14|
|  2|   4|  4|
|  2|   8|  4|
|  2|  10| 10|
|  2|  11| 10|
|  2|  11| 10|
|  2|  12| 10|
|  2|  13| 10|
|  2|  20| 20|
+---+----+---+
```

Comment: Does this work with different ids in your source dataframe ? I am not sure. 
I am even surprised that this solution actually works. If you work on a cluster I believe that there is no guarantee that the "map" will be performed sequentially.

Comment: @Simon Modified it so it works with different id's. I'm running all tests locally so I don't yet know if it'll run correctly on a cluster either. Any alternative is welcome.